# Is there a way to open a code directory using Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, linux

I just recently installed this version of Linux and when ever I do `code fileName` in the terminal it makes a whole new file. IS there a way for me to open an already existing code file I have?

Thanks for taking your time and effort to answer this question!

Comment: Give the path to a file that already exists

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is!

You need to be on the same folder of the file. For example, if the path of your file is `/home/Downloads/` you need to use `cd Downloads` and then try to open the file. However, note that the `code` command that you are trying to use is the default command to open the file in the vscode. If you want to open the file using the default text editor in Linux, usually you have to write `gedit filename` in your terminal

Comment: Otherwise, you can run the command by passing the file's path before the file's name:

`code home/Downloads/filename`

Comment: I'm still confused. My files is located in `C:/Users/Jake/Desktop/CODE/Rock-Paper-Scissors`, do I type this in to the terminal?

Comment: Are u using windows? If you're using linux, you can just type `cd users/Jake/Desktop/CODE/` and then `code Rock-Paper-Scissors` or just `code .` to open every file in the folder in VSCODE.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I open the directory of the project and run command `code .`

This opens it with VSCode, but that's okay because most often I will need all other files anyways. Brackets is `brackets .`